# Problemas declaracion clase abstracta

Tags: java

estoy tratando crear la siguiente jerarquía. tengo una clase abstracta llamada persona de la siguiente manera.

```
public abstract class Persona {

protected String nombre;
protected String apellidos;
protected final String dni;


public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}
public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
public String getApellidos() {
    return apellidos;
}
public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
    this.apellidos = apellidos;
}
public String getDni() {
    return dni;
}
```

de la cual necesito crear una clase llamada socio que herede de esta clase persona. el problema viene que como no se puede instanciar desde una clase abstracta necesito hacerlo desde la clase socio pero me salta un error con el atributo final DNI. el código de la clase socio es el siguiente.

```
package Biblioteca;

public class Socio extends Persona {

public Socio(String nombre, String apellidos, String dni) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellidos = apellidos;
    this.dni = dni;

}
```

}

el caso que el atributo DNI tiene que ser final y no consigo realizarlo.

Comment: una variable final solo puede ser inicializada una vez pero porque va a ser final si puedes acceder a traves de la clase?

Comment: la variable se supone que una vez inicializada con un valor no se puede modificar por ello la puse como final.  Se supone que la clase socio debería de heredar  de persona, el problema es que  como no la inicializo en la case persona pues da error.

Comment: El codigo que has copiado no compila, ya que la variable dni esta declarada como final y no la has inicializado.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que deberías crear un constructor en la clase abstracta, algo así:

```
public abstract class Persona {

protected String nombre;
protected String apellidos;
protected final String dni;

public Persona(String nombre, String apellidos, String dni) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellidos= apellidos;
    this.dni= dni;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}
public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
public String getApellidos() {
    return apellidos;
}
public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
    this.apellidos = apellidos;
}
public String getDni() {
    return dni;
}
}
```

Y después utilizarlo desde el constructor de la clase socio.

```
public class Socio extends Persona {
    public Socio(String nombre, String apellidos, String dni) {
        super(nombre, apellidos, dni);
    }
}
```

Espero te sirva.

¡Suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias Gustavo pero el problema es que lo que quiero hacer es que no se pueda modificar una vez puesto el valor del atributo DNI.

Comment: Ya modifiqué la respuesta.  Seguro así te sirve.